# SignalR Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'userName')

Tags: .net-core, signalr, http-proxy

I am using SignalR behind a [node.js proxy](https://gitlab.com/hesamian/milwaukee-internationals-app/-/blob/master/webpack.config.js) and I get this error:

```
{"error":"An unexpected error occurred during connection handshake. AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'userName'))"}
```

Is SignalR trying to authenticate the connection because I already added [`[AllowAnonymous]`](https://gitlab.com/hesamian/milwaukee-internationals-dotnet/-/blob/master/DAL/Utilities/LogHub.cs) or proxy server causes messages to be malformed because [I used JSON transfer format](https://gitlab.com/hesamian/milwaukee-internationals-app/-/blob/master/utilities/signalr.js#L9) to make sure messages are readable so I can see if there is any issue.

[image]

Firefox logs:
[image]

[Backend](https://gitlab.com/hesamian/milwaukee-internationals-dotnet/-/blob/master/API/Startup.cs#L150)

```
        services.AddSignalR(config =>
        {
            config.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 mega-bytes
            config.StreamBufferCapacity = 50;
            config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        }).AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol();
```

[React-Native SignalR](https://gitlab.com/hesamian/milwaukee-internationals-app/-/blob/master/utilities/signalr.js#L5)

```
const signalR = new signalRBuilder.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(prefixUrl('/log'))
  .configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .withHubProtocol(new JsonHubProtocol())
  .build();

signalR.start();
```

React-native project:

- [repository](https://gitlab.com/hesamian/milwaukee-internationals-app)
- To run: `npm run web`

[.NET web application](https://gitlab.com/hesamian/milwaukee-internationals-dotnet)

Comment: It would help if you share the signalR part from the frontend and backend. The community can just guess what is happening. I would guess that the "AllowAnonymous" is the issue. If you don't have any authentication you won't have a user name in your user principle.

Answer (score 1):

when redirecting using an application you may lose header information which can cause some errors in signalR

Comment: I will try to open your solutions later to try to help you better, but try to connect a device directly without the proxy and see if it works if it does limit your problem to the proxy